# Do $http request from Angular Interceptor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to implement Angular Interceptor for Exceptions. For one at least. I have a token and when it old enogh backend throws `TokenAlmostExpired exception`. This exception contains `errorCode = 101`. In the interceptor I'm checking that code is 101 and then I need to send `POST request` to backend's `/refresh endpoint` so I could refresh token.

```
.factory('errorInjector',['$injector', function ($q, $injector) {

    var vm = this;

    var errorInjector = {
        'response': function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        },
        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            if (JSON.stringify(rejection.data.errorCode) === JSON.stringify(101)) {
                vm.getRefreshToken();
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
    return errorInjector;
}]);
```

and

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorInjector');
    }]);
```

**$http**

But there's a problem at interceptor level, that I can't just give it dependency on `$http`, because there's `Circular dependency found: $http <- errorInjector <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state`

**$scope**

And I can't put `getRefreshToken()` function to `$scope`, because $scope dependency also gives 'Circular dependency'.

**$Injector**

```
var http = $injector.get('$http');
```

doesn't work as well, and gives me erorr.

So how can I catch exception in interceptor and then do a $http request from there?

Comment: You may want to consider firing off an event, and picking it up in a service and doing the execution from there

Comment: Don't use rootscope, create your own event aggregator...

Comment: Can you show full errorInjector code? It seems that it is not full implementation.

Comment: We don't need full errorInjector code, there is enough there

Comment: I do not think so. It has $injector injected that should be used to avoid circural dependency .

Comment: Using `$injector` is a code smell to me

Comment: Here is an [event aggregator pattern implementation](https://plnkr.co/edit/hsQ1HjZUK9yWlp7htvEc?p=preview) if you want a full on example with your code just ask

Comment: @CallumLinington I've never done anything with event, so I'd really like to get some help on that, thanks. As long as I understand it supposed to be easy  .broadcast("something), .subscribe('something), right?

Comment: Yeah, if you look at my plnker it should be fairly obvious to what is going on

Comment: @CallumLinington, not really there's a lot of letters that I don't get. What is "t" and "ev", for instance?

Comment: @ottercoder if you do not understand @CallumLinington code it seems that you do not understant DI in angular, thats why you have `'$injector', function ($q, $injector)` which should be `'$q', '$injector', function ($q, $injector)` and thats probably your problem here

Comment: Yeah, would agree with @pawlakppp on this

Comment: If I'd understand Angular completely,  I would'nt need a help at all. But I've found a solution. I'm putting function from service to $rootScope and calling it as a promise. 
`$q.get('$rootScope').vmRT.getRefreshToken(); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've done it with service. Thanks everyone!

**interceptor:**

```
.factory('errorInjector',['$injector', function ($q, $injector) {

    var errorInjector = {
        'response': function (response) {
            ....
        },
        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            if (JSON.stringify(rejection.data.errorCode) === JSON.stringify(101)) {
                var refreshTokenService = $q.get('refreshTokenService');
                refreshTokenService.refreshTokenService();
                $.notify({message: data.data.detailMessage}, {type: 'warning'});
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };

    return errorInjector;
}]);
```

**refreshTokenService:**

```
.service('refreshTokenService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    this.refreshTokenService = function () {
        $http.post('/refresh').then(
            function success(response) {
               .....
            },
            function error(data) {
                .....
            }
        );
    };
```

}])
;

Answer (score 1):

Interceptor

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('services').factory("httpInterceptor", [
        'errorLauncher',
        '$q',
        function (errorLauncher, $q) {
            return {
                'requestError': function (rejection) {
                    if (rejection.status === 101) {
                        errorLauncher.pushInErrorMessage(rejection);
                    }
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                },
                'responseError': function (rejection) {
                    if (rejection.status === 101) {
                        errorLauncher.pushInErrorMessage(rejection);
                    }
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            };
        }]);
})(angular);
```

and error handler service

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('services').factory("errorLauncher", [
        '$rootScope',
        function ($rootScope) {
            return {
                'pushInErrorMessage': function (rejection) {
                    $rootScope.$emit('theTokenWillDieSoon');
                }
            };
        }]);
})(angular);
```

and now main app controller

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('controllers').controller("globalCtrl", [
        '$rootScope',
        '$http',
        function ($rootScope, $http) {
            $rootScope.$on('theTokenWillDieSoon', function () {
                // http from here
            });
        }]);
})(angular);
```

Comment: `Circular dependency found: $http <- errorLauncher <- httpInterseptor <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state` :/

Comment: try the $emit from error handler then ) hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

> .factory('errorInjector',['$injector', function ($q, $injector) { .... }]);

Change To:

> .factory('errorInjector',['$q', function ($q) { .... }]);